# How do we avoid boilerplate code in files transpiled by Babel?

Tags: javascript, build, babeljs, code-translation

For example, if I run

```
babel src --source-maps --out-dir . --modules common
```

on the src folder of my project, it output all the files in ., but each and every file contains things like

```
var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

var _get = function get(_x, _x2, _x3) { var _again = true; _function: while (_again) { var object = _x, property = _x2, receiver = _x3; desc = parent = getter = undefined; _again = false; if (object === null) object = Function.prototype; var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property); if (desc === undefined) { var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(object); if (parent === null) { return undefined; } else { _x = parent; _x2 = property; _x3 = receiver; _again = true; continue _function; } } else if ('value' in desc) { return desc.value; } else { var getter = desc.get; if (getter === undefined) { return undefined; } return getter.call(receiver); } } };

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function'); } }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }
```

Is it somehow possible to have babel write these common boilerplate things to a file, then use require in each file to import them? So the boilerplate code in each file might now look like this:

```
var { _createClass, _get, _interopRequireDefault, _classCallCheck, _inherits } = require(`./babel-functions`)
```

and the `babel-functions.js` file (or whatever it shall be named) would be located in the `--out-dir`, which is `.` in my case, and all files would have that require statement at the top. Files in folders would have `require(../babel-functions)`, `require(../../babel-functions)`, etc.

Is there some type of option to do this (or similar) with Babel?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33703919

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`external-helpers`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/external-helpers/) is one option, and alternatively you should use [`runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/), which is more along the lines of what you suggested in that all of the helpers are loaded via `require()`. `runtime` also automatically adds references to a polyfill for you, so you would also not do `require('babel/polyfill')` when using runtime. The only downside of `runtime` is that because if avoids polluting globals, new prototype methods like `Array.prototype.fill` do not work and require non-standard code to be used. `runtime` is great for writing libraries especially though.

Answer (score 3):

Babel provides the ability to use external helpers, instead of inlining them, using `babel --external-helpers` on the command line or `babel.transform("code", { externalHelpers: true });` when calling Babel through the API.

When using either of these, Babel will assume a variable `babelHelpers` defined with it's helpers.

Requiring `babel-core/external-helpers` (after installing `babel-core` from NPM) will inject the helpers into `global` on node.

Other methods of generating and inserting the helpers are documented at the documentation: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/external-helpers.