# How to use Babel 6 external helpers in the browser?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

First the question:

**Where can I find the external-helpers.js script, or how can I build the external-helpers for Babel 6?**

In Babel 5.x, I was able to use the `externalHelpers` option, which required including `external-helpers.js`, which used to be in the babel-core package. Moving on to Babel 6, I see that external-helpers is now [external-helpers-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-external-helpers-2) plugin. This does the job of including the relevant `babelHelper` calls in my transpiled code, but that is it; I need the actual helper definitions!

In the issue [add missing build script for `external-helpers.js`](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/2768), it is suggested to " build it yourself with the CLI". I don't see any CLI options that seem to deal with building external helpers.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions. `babel` is for questions for a *Python library* with said name.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, @FelixKling.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to build the `external-helpers.js` with the [babel-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core) package and the Node REPL:

```
var helperBuilder = require('./lib/tools/build-external-helpers');
fs.writeFileSync('external-helpers.js', helperBuilder());
```

I imagine that, depending on your situation, you could also build the external helpers file by build script (Grunt, Gulp, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The CLI command referred to in the issue you mention is `babel-external-helpers`, which is part of the `babel-cli` npm package. With the `babel-cli` package installed, running `babel-external-helpers --help` gives the following self-explanatory output:

```
Usage: babel-external-helpers [options]

Options:

-h, --help                   output usage information
-l, --whitelist [whitelist]  Whitelist of helpers to ONLY include
-t, --output-type [type]     Type of output (global|umd|var)
```

It simply outputs the file to stdout, so to print the code to a file, you do `babel-external-helpers [options] > babel-helpers.js`.